# Objective-C: What does getter= actually do in @property?

Tags: objective-c

This code:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property(getter=myProp) NSString *prop;

@end

@implementation AnotherClass

- (void)test {
    SomeClass *s = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    NSString *x = s.prop;
    NSString *y = s.myProp;
}

@end
```

Both x and y are the value of the same property, I got two getters, one is `-myProp` and the other is `-prop`, so does declaring getter add **another** getter besides the auto-generated getter?

If this is right, can I use `getter=` to generate more than one getter?

Also, how do I remove the auto-generated `-prop` getter?

Comment: There is no auto-generated getter method named `prop`. It is named `myProp`. Try it. Change your code to `NSString *x = [s prop];`. It won't compile due to unknown method.

Answer (score 2):

The `@property` syntax is really a convenient way to tell Objective-C to synthesize two methods for you:

```
- (void) setProp:(NSString*)value {
    _prop = value ;
}
- (NSString*) prop {
    return _prop ;
}
```

Note that, depending on `nonatomic` vs `atomic`, it may add threading synchronization in there also.

So, when you write:

```
NSLog ( object.prop ) ;
```

You're really writing:

```
NSLog ( [object prop] ) ;
```

If you set a getter like you did, it actually creates these methods:

```
- (void) setProp:(NSString*)value {
    _prop = value ;
}
- (NSString*) myProp {
    return _prop ;
}
```

So, these two lines:

```
NSLog ( object.prop ) ; // prop is a property with a getter, so it uses [object myProp]
NSLog ( object.myProp ) ; // myProp isn't a known property, so it assumes it's [object myProp]
```

Turn in to:

```
NSLog ( [object myProp] ) ;
NSLog ( [object myProp] ) ;
```